# Extract values from list of dictionaries and populate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my Class component, I have a list of 9 dictionaries as `props`:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Each dictionary key, value structure:

```
{name:'John', position:'fwd'}, {name:'Peter', position:'mid'}, {name:'Bill', position:'def'},...
```

---

Now I need to extract dictionary 'name' values and display them as text in my component.

For every group of three rows, the value must satisfy the condition of its unique 'position', that is, 3 names for 'fwd', then 3 names for 'mid', then names 3 for 'def', until the list is emptied.

---

This is the render:

```
  render() {
    const { players } = this.props;

    if(players){
        return (
         <div className="app">
            <div className="pos-wrapper">
              <div className="row">
                <Position>FWD Name 1</Position> 
                <Position>FWD Name 2</Position>
                <Position>FWD Name 3</Position> 
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <Position>MID Name 1</Position> 
                <Position>MID Name 2</Position> 
                <Position>MID Name 3</Position> 
              </div>
                <div className="row">
                <Position>DEF Name 1</Position> 
                <Position>DEF Name 2</Position> 
                <Position>DEF Name 3</Position>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      else{
        return null
        }
    }
}
```

---

Examples of expected result:

```
FWD NAME 1 -> John
...
...
MID NAME 1 -> Peter
...
...
DEF NAME 1 -> Bill
...
...
```

---

How do I extract the values using that condition and keeping the structure above?

Comment: Javascript has several array functions such as map, filter, and reduce. Filter and then map is most likely what you're looking for.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map I'm too tired to double check my syntax, but maybe this will get you on the right path: `              {players.filter(player => player.position === "fwd").map(player => <Position>FWD {player.name}</Position>)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is how i would do it.

```
  render() {
    const { players } = this.props;

    if(players){
        return (
         <div className="app">
            <div className="pos-wrapper">
            {players.map((player,i)=>(
              <div key={i} className="row">
              {
                {
                  'fwd': <Position>FWD Name {player.name}</Position> ,
                  'mid': <Position>MID Name {player.name}</Position>,
                  'def': <Position>DEF Name {player.name}</Position> ,
                  
                }[player.position]
              }

              </div>
            ))}

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      else{
        return null
        }
    }
```

Edited: It doesn't feel like it's an good idea but i guess following would give you the correct output

```
  render() {
    const { players } = this.props;

    if(players){
        return (
         <div className="app">
            <div className="pos-wrapper">
             <div className="row">
              {players.map((player,i)=>(
               {(player.position==="fwd")?
                  <Position key={i}>FWD Name {player.name}</Position>
               }
                   
              ))}

             </div>
             <div  className="row">
              {players.map((player,i)=>(
               {(player.position==="mid")?
                  <Position  key={i} >MID Name {player.name}</Position>
               }
                   
              ))}

            </div>
            <div  className="row">
              {players.map((player,i)=>(
               {(player.position==="def")?
                  <Position  key={i} >DEF Name {player.name}</Position>
               }
                   
              ))}

             </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      else{
        return null
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: Note that i is the list index

Comment: values are mapped correctly. problem is the structure is altered, and there goes the layout. I had three rows of squares, with three columns, and not I have 9 rows. can I not extract manually by index?

Comment: @8-BitBorges I have an another idea but it's just not optimal. three loops with conditional rendering on each of them. I just don't think it's good idea

Comment: oh please can I see it?

Comment: @8-BitBorges Updated. It's definitely not optimal in scenarios where you have many people and positions. but this was mainly the idea for it

Answer (score 1):

I have used `Array.reduce` to convert the the data into groups according to the positions.

```js
const App = (props) => {
  
const formatData = (data) => {
  const finalRes = data.reduce((res, {position, name}) => {
    if(res[position]) {
      res[position].push({position, name})
    } else {
      res[position] = [
        {position, name}
      ]
    }

    return res;
  },[]);
  return Object.values(finalRes);
}

  return formatData(props.data).map(d => {
    return d.map(obj => {
      return (
        <div key={`${obj.name}_${obj.position}`}>
          {obj.position.toUpperCase()} {obj.name}
        </div>
      )
    })
  })
}

const data = [
  { name: 'John 1', position: 'fwd' },
  { name: 'John 2', position: 'fwd' },
  { name: 'John 3', position: 'fwd' },
  { name: 'Peter 1', position: 'mid' },
  { name: 'Peter 2', position: 'mid' },
  { name: 'Peter 3', position: 'mid' },
  { name: 'Bill 1', position: 'def' },
  { name: 'Bill 2', position: 'def' },
  { name: 'Bill 3', position: 'def' }
];

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data}/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how filter and map can work together:

```js
function DisplayPlayers({players, position}) {
  return players.filter(player => player.position === position).map((player, index) => <div key={player.name}>{player.position.toUpperCase()} {player.name} {index+1}</div>);
}

function Application({players}) {
  return <div>
    <DisplayPlayers players={players} position="fwd" />
    <DisplayPlayers players={players} position="mid" />
    <DisplayPlayers players={players} position="def" />
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application players={[{name:'John', position:'fwd'},{name:'Jason', position:'fwd'}, {name:'Jones', position:'fwd'},{name:'Peter', position:'mid'}, {name:'Frank', position:'def'},{name:'Bill', position:'def'}]} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```